# Querying through NHibernate using a Interface in Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orchardcms

I am storing records in order to link 2 part records together in `Orchard (CMS)`.
The records will have a reference to the 2 items they are linking.
There are several tables of records doing this, and they all implement the same interface.

```
//One example of a record implementing the common interface
//This relation links a member to a home
public class HomeToMemberRelationRecord : IRelationResultable
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [Aggregate]
    public virtual MemberPartRecord MemberPartRecord { get; set; }
    [Aggregate]
    public virtual HomePartRecord HomePartRecord { get; set; }

    //The interface is implemented here
    //...
}
```

I am trying to query these records in a generic way using the interface.
I have a generic method accepting the type and resolving the `IRepository` from that type.
The problem is the properties I want to use in the query differ for each record.
On the above record I may want to get the `Member`'s from a `Home`, however another record might be linking a `Dog` to a `DogHouse` and I want to find all `Dog`'s in the `DogHouse`.
The UI element fetching the relations will resolve the repository when needed:

```
Resolve<IRepository<T>>();
```

So there is no way to know if the query should be:

```
.Where(x => x.HomePartRecord.ContentItemRecord.Id == id)
//or
.Where(x => x.DogHousePartRecord.ContentItemRecord.Id == id)
```

So the interface implemented by the relation records must define how they themselves are to be queried.

I tried using a method to return the property I needed to query, but `NHibernate` did not like that and served me a `NotSupportedException`.

```
// Method in the interface
int GetId();

// Attempt to call above method from a query.
var repo = _services.WorkContext.Resolve<IRepository<T>>(); //Constraint: where T : IMemberSearchResultable, new()
var relations = repo.Table.Where(x => x.GetRelevantId() == id);
```

I tried using a property in my interface instead, but `NHibernate` would simply look for the property on the record in the database (It only exists in the model).

```
// Attempt to use a property in the interface instead of a method.
int RelevantId { get; set; } //Usage: .Where(x => x.RelevantId == id)
```

So I tried building an expression:
(Spoiler: This also failed.)

```
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression<T>(string propertyName, int filterValue)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
        var method = typeof(int).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(int) });
        var body = Expression.Call(property, method, Expression.Constant(filterValue));
        return (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
    }

    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> TestGet<T>(int id)
    {
        return GetExpression<T>("MemberPartRecord.ContentItemRecord.Id", id);
    }
```

I have tried a number of approaches to naming the property, but can not find one that works.
I can of course build the specific query I need in each case without using an interface. Which leads me to believe it should be possible to build the same query using the interface.

Am I building the expression wrong, is it the wrong approach or is the entire idea far fetched?

Comment: Not all `Equals` were (initially?) supported by [tag:linq-to-nhibernate] (but `==` operator was fully supported). Maybe are you just hitting this issue in your built expression. You may then try [to extend the linq provider with those additional `Equals`](http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/nhibernate-3-extending-linq-provider-fix-notsupportedexception).

Comment: I think I may at some point have hit that issue, but calling Expression.Equal() instead to set the method resolved that (Presumably as it resolves to == instead of Equals). However in the end my main remaining issue seems to be this: "MemberPartRecord.ContentItemRecord.Id". I seem to only be able to access the properties that are directly on the C# model for the Record. I will post what I have as a potential answer, however my current solution doesn't fully solve this issue.

Comment: Maybe should you add in your question a more concrete example of the situation. Like some class definition excerpt illustrating the case. It looks to me it is something like `class E1: IOrchard { someType P1 {get; } IOrchard.SomeProp { get { return P1;} } ...}`, `class E2: IOrchard { someType P2 {get; } IOrchard.SomeProp { get { return P2;} } ...}`, and you have your mapping explicitly on P1 and P2, while wishing to query on those properties generically, with the same expression. Is it this?

Comment: I added some more details and examples to the question. But basically, yes, what you're saying sounds to me like what I am trying to do. And I managed to actually get something working which I posted as a possible answer. However it will not let me access properties on referenced records in the query, only properties directly on the records in the table being queried. (Good enough for me, for now, but not a full answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Changing mappings

If changing the mapping (and probably the interface altogether) is an option, you should try mapping your entities as inheriting from your common interface, as illustrated in [inheritance mapping documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/inheritance.html). It should works without a base class.

But this would mean your interface would define some `HomeBase` property (typed as a base class or another common interface) which would the mapped one, and which would exists as such in your entities.

Then you would add some specialized `ConcreteHome` or `DogHouse` property on your entities, not mapped, and casting the `HomeBase` to the concrete home.

### Probable issues

Beware of proxies, such setting would probably force you to use `lazy="no-proxy"` or `lazy="false"` on `HomeBase` property mapping.

Moreover, [a post](/a/3612883/1178314) writes this is not supported in Fluent mapping (I use .hbm files).

And on top of that, if you need querying the related Home specific properties (not belonging to `HomeBase`), you would then have a new trouble.

## Going farer into runtime type inspection

You may instead go farer with your current approach. But this will require quite some tinkering.

The aim would be to get a more capable helper:

```cs
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression<T, U>(
    Expression<Func<I, BaseHome>> interfaceHomePropertySelector, U filterValue)
```

The helper implementation should get the interface property memberInfo, and then infer the corresponding member in `T` entity. From that, it would construct the adequate expression.

For performances reasons, the resulting inferring should then be cached for reducing runtime cost of subsequent uses.

### Dirty inferring

You may infer the concrete property in `T` by checking all its properties and take the first which is compatible with the interface property, while not having the same name as the interface property. This requires having only a single Home property in each of your entities.

### Harder inferring

You may go a quite more elaborated way to get the right property: runtime evaluation of what get actually called when accessing the interface property on an instance of `T`. For that, you would need to use the same proxyfying approach than NHibernate uses for handling lazy-loading.

Instantiate a new dummy instance of a `T` proxy, instrumented for calling a callback of yours at each property access. Access the interface property. Your callback should fires at least twice : at interface property access, then at the concrete property access the interface implementation should do.

So in your callback you would then have to inspect the call-stack to check in which case you are, and infer the concrete property of T.

Answer (score 0):

**I am posting what I have so far as an answer, but I hope someone out there has a better solution:**

I have managed to get a working solution for my specific problem, but it's not a perfect solution as it does not allow you to use references in your query.
I can basically only refer to properties that are present on the C# record mapped to the database.

This is the method I am currently using:

```
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression<T, U>(string propertyName, U filterValue)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName), 
            Expression.Constant(filterValue)), parameter);
        return predicate;
    }
```

And I call it this way:

```
GetExpression<T, U>("MemberPartRecord", rec);
```

The significant difference here is that I am now querying the `MemberPartRecord` rather than trying to access `MemberPartRecord.ContentItemRecord.Id`
For my current needs this is enough, but only because I am in a position to provide the record I need for the query.

I will not accept this answer in the hopes that someone can provide a complete answer that allows the use of referenced records in the query.

Comment: Are your referenced records of a known concrete type at the moment you write your querying expression, or not? If not, my coming answer second solution will not help you.

Comment: Technically yes. Although my goal was to make the process of adding a new type easier, so the developer would only need to use "GetExpression<T, U>("MemberPartRecord", rec);" to define what record should be used. Unfortunately I don't know how the inheritance mapping works in Orchard (I am trying to find out now). There are forces pulling me away from this task for a while though, since it is currently working. I will be back again on this task soon, and hopefully by then I will have gotten some more feedback from the Orchard team on Gitter.